# Flask web service on Apache (Linux Guest) cannot be accessed from Host (Windows)

Tags: python, apache, flask, virtualbox

I have a Windows 10 Host running a Linux Mint Guest via VirtualBox. On Linux, I have built a Python-Flask web service with Visual Studio Code, and hosted on Apache 2.

On the Guest:

- http://127.0.0.1/ returns the Apache landing page. Successful.
- When debugging the code within VSC, http://127.0.0.1:5000 and http://0.0.0.0:5000 return the web service methods. Successful.
- XX.com reutrns the web service methods. Successful.
- http://192.168.56.101 returns the Apache landing page. Successful.

The service instance is located at: /var/www/ZZ. The follwing is the dictory structure:

- __init__.py
- ZZ.wsgi
- static folder (empty)
- templates folder (empty)

The __init__.py implementation has the following:

```
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

The ZZ.wsgi implementation is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/ZZ")
from __init__ import app as application
```

On the /etc/apache2/sites-available/ the configuration ZZ.conf is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName XX.com
 WSGIDaemonProcess ZZ user=YY group=YY threads=5
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/ZZ/ZZ.wsgi
 <Directory /var/www/ZZ>
  WSGIProcessGroup ZZ
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and I have run: sudo a2ensite ZZ, i.e. there is already a link to ZZ.conf in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.

The hosts file in the /etc/ has the following:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   YY-VirtualBox
192.168.56.101  XX.com
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I have run: sudo service apache2 restart.

Running: id -gn, and; id -Gn, confirms the user YY and the group YY.

Also, the Apache version is: Apache/2.4.18. Python version is: 3.5.2.

On the Host (Windows 10):

- http://127.0.0.1/ returns "cannot be reached". Successful (nothing is hosted on Windows).
- http://127.0.0.1:8080 returns the Apache landing page. Successful.
- http://192.168.56.101 returns the Apache landing page. Successful.
- XX.com returns "cannot be reached" - which is the problem.

My VirtualBox Network settings are:

- Adaptor 1. NAT. No port forwarding.
- Adaptor 2. Host-only.

So - the question is how to reach XX.com from Host (Windows 10)? I.e. how to call/access the web service from external callers (to Linux Guest)?

I have tried port forwarding with no luck. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some Google-ing, I found that doing the following resolves this:

1. Added a Port-forwarding rule in VirtualBox as:

   - Name: Apache.
   - Protocol: TCP.
   - Host IP: [empty].
   - Host port: 8080.
   - Guest IP: [empty].
   - Guest port: 80.
2. On the Host, I have edited the file "hosts" in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc adding the following line:
   192.168.56.101  XX.com

Note that my FireWall is OFF on the Guest. I can now access XX.com from the Host.